# where() if variable is not equal to null

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to perform a operation that means

`if $this_variable_1 is not null 
   perform a where() with $this_variable_variable1
 end if`

`if $this_variable_1 and $this_variable_2 is not null 
   perform a where() with $this_variable_1 and a where() with $this_variable_2
 end if`

However, I have four variables, and not all of them are going to be valid, and there will be different combinations of which ones are valid and which ones are null, now I could write 36 if() statements or a switch but I feel this would be very ineffective.

Does Laravel or PHP have a feature that could perform this operation without all of the if() statements?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Show us some code so we can help you better :)

Comment: @Mozammil All I have written right now is getting data from a post request and getting the pre-search data. I do not have any code written right now related to the question.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what's the context of the code, you should provide more context where this is going to take place. But if you are looking at Model and querying db then i would suggest [When](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses) of laravel eloquent

Comment: @AidenKaiser It would be hard for anybody to give you a good answer. In any case, the `where()` class accepts an array as well. You could look into constructing an array of available search filters instead of writing multiple conditional statements. I would be able to help you better if I see some code :)

Comment: @Mozammil What I'm trying to accomplish is a `->whereOrAny()`, all I want it to do is if it does not find something that matches then it just doesn't perform the `where()`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using conditional clauses

`->when(!empty($this_variable_1) , function ($query) use($this_variable_1){
return $query->where('myColumn', '=', $this_variable_1);
})`

Comment: Laravel has a built in `whereNotNull()` function in the [Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereNotNull), so you can call `$query->whereNotNull('yourColumn')